# Eclipse How do I set my compiler to 1.5

Tags: java, eclipse

I was trying to com compile a project I imported into eclipse and got a error saying my compiler compliance had to be 1.5.  For a quick fix it had change project to 1.5 or workspace to 1.5

I choose the change workspace to 1.5 and now get the following error
“the compiler compliance has been changed to 1.5 , but no 1.5 jre could not be found in the installed jres.  You have to manually set the correct jre or add a new one”

How do I set my compiler to 1.5?

Comment: which JRE you have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can change the version of the java compiler only make right click in your porject and select version of java, I guest that you have install jdk you need.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

From the menu bar: Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler

Enable project specific settings (checked) Uncheck "use Compliance from execution environment '.... Select the desired "compiler compliance level"

That will allow you to compile "1.5" code using a "1.6" JDK.

**Configure JDK:**

If you want to actually use a 1.5 JDK to produce "1.5" compliant code, then install a suitable 1.5 JDK and tell eclipse where it is installed via:

Window -> preferences -> Installed JREs

And then go back to your project

Project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> libraries

remove the 1.6 system libaries, and: add library... -> JRE System LIbrary -> Alternate JRE -> The JRE you want.

Verify that the correct JRE is on the project's build path, save everything, and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Go to   `Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler`

[Eclipse Docs](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user/topics/tchangejavalevel.html)

[image]